# Redirect domains on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, server

I have been doing research for hours on stack overflow but can't seem to find anything that works for me. I am not sure if its my server setup or what but here is what I am faced with.

I have a live version of a web app and a beta test version as well. The folder structures are exactly the same. I want the data to be consistent for both the live and beta versions. I use the same MySQL tables for this. There is 1 folder with images that I want to redirect someone using my beta version to the live version. For example:

If someone types in https://beta.example.com/images/ImageName I want them to be redirected to https://live.example.com/images/ImageName

I assume the best way to do this is using .htaccess, but I am open to suggestions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache, this can easily be done with it's `.htaccess` file as you suggest.

However your question tagged `nginx`. As a more performance oriented server `nginx` likes to avoid per-directory config files like Apache's `.htaccess`.  Are you using Apache or `nginx`?

Here is one basic way in Apache:

1. Configure both beta / live sites as normal.
2. In the beta site's config (or `.htaccess`), use a `RewriteRule` matching the rewrite this to the live version. Or the reverse. See the examples from the official docs.  In particular: [From Old to New - Internal](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new) and the [substitution](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) examples.

Here is an untested example:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^images(.*)" "https://live.example.com/images$1"
```

See [this page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) for the way nginx would do it.

Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond! Anyhow, yes I am using nginx. I am looking into the page now. Thanks for your help!